# JavaScript call using HtmlUnit

Tags: java, javascript, htmlunit

I'm trying to get page content, that javascript function `getWines()` returns. The page I'm trying to get info from is http://hedonism.co.uk/wines/. So I'm using HtmlUnit and wrote the following code:

```
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(
            BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_10);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
    String javaScriptCode = "getWines(1)";
    ScriptResult result = page.executeJavaScript(javaScriptCode);
    Page page1 = result.getNewPage();
    StringBuffer p = WebGet.getBuffPageContent(page1.getUrl().toString(), true);
    System.out.println(p.toString());
```

But it seems such approach isn't working. I receive the same page I had before function call with the same source code, so I'm not able to get info about, for example, wine name. Maybe I'm totally doing incorrect?

Comment: Just a guess: you disable javascript `setJavaScriptEnabled(false)` but a few lines later you expect HtmlUnit to `executeJavaScript`. I haven't studied the HtmlUnit code but this sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: @Markus I changed to true, but it still isn't working

Comment: According the JavaDoc `executeJavaScript()` performs the same action like you enter `javascript:getWines(1)` in the address bar. In FF 28.x it results in an exception. Do you mind to allow "script errors" by enabling `setThrowExceptionOnScriptError`?

Comment: @Markus, I allowed script errors, but I didn't get any script related exceptions.